# Angular Dropdown list not reading value

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular so forgive me if I have this whole thing wrong. I'm attempting to get a created list in a dropdown and when the user selects it, it should record the information to the database.

Here is my code:
**Component.html**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Retrieval Reason</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="RR" required>
    <mat-option>--</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let reason of reasons" [value]="reason">
      {{reason.reason}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error *ngIf="RR.hasError('required')">Please choose a reason</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

  <button
    mat-raised-button
    (click)="done()"
    color="primary"
    [disabled]="selection.selected.length === 0 || RR.hasError('required')"
  >
    Retrieve
  </button>
```

**Component.ts**

```
  retrievalReason: Reasons;
    RR = new FormControl('', Validators.required);

  reasons: Reasons[] = [
    {reason: 'Cycle Count'},
    {reason: 'Purge Request'},
    {reason: 'Picking'},];

    done() {
    this.dialogRef.close({
      carrier: this.carrier,
      destination: this.selection.selected[0].dstId,
      retrievalReason: this.RR.get('reasons').value,
    });
  }
```

I've looked up the Angular method to reading a value from a dropdown list and have tried different variable names, nothing's worked so far.

Comment: Could you provide a stackblitz with your issue? The only thing I see that could be wrong is that you try `retrievalReason: this.RR.get('reasons').value` but this is for a form to get the formcontrol. You only have a formcontrol so just `retrievalReason:this.RR.value` should be enough.

Comment: That worked. Just removed the .get. Thanks :)

Comment: Good that it worked, if you could accept this as the answer. This way other people can also see that this was the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I see that could be wrong is that you try `retrievalReason: this.RR.get('reasons').value` but this is for a form to get the formcontrol.

You only have a formcontrol so just `retrievalReason:this.RR.value` should be enough.